# How to popup and dismiss the viewcontrollers from root view controller in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a MainViewController and i am Presenting another viewcontroller(2nd ViewController) through 
[self PresentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
And this modalViewController is a NavigationController from this i am pushing to DetailViewController.
Now in DetailViewController if i click on a button i should go to MainViewController directly.

I am doing [self popToRootViewController] and [2nd viewcontroller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

but i am not getting, the above code taking me to 2nd view controller not to the mainviewcontroller.

any one have any idea about how we can do this.please share your ideas or sample code to achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSNotification. In your detailview controller when the button is pressed, you can post a notification. In the mainViewController you can keep a notification observer. Then upon receiving notification, you can fire a method to dissmiss the modalviewcontroller.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply Adarsh V C, I will try that, i think this will work, great idea at great time, thank you very much.

Comment: :) you can use delegation pattern also in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what you are really trying to ask.

But still, if I am guessing right, try calling `[mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: Hi Vaibhav Tekam, than kyou for quick reply. I have Navigated to two levels of ViewControllers from MainViewController first level is i did presentedModalViewController(this is navigation controller) and at second level i navigated to detailviewcontroller through pushviewcontroller, now i need to go back directly to mainviewcontroller. i hope it is clear now.